# How to merge PDFs into a PDFA1b with watermarks using iText5

Tags: pdf, itext

Here is what I need to do:

- Merge several PDF documents (which may or may not be PDFA) into one PDFA1b.
- Add a watermark (a simple text label) on each page of the resulting PDF.

It has to be with iText 5

I have looked at this official merging example: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/adding-cover-page-existing-pdf

But can this method be used to create a PDFA, and also add watermarks? 
Or am I stuck with using this other method which he specifically says not to use: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents-itext5/how-not-merge-documents

Answer (score 1):

You can create files that conform to PDF/A-1b with just about any PDF library including iText. PDF/A, in general, is a subset of ISO 32000 (PDF) so it's really just a matter of using the tool to do what you need to with the files but **not** adding anything that is forbidden by PDF/A-1b (in your case).

The thing to be aware of is that iText or any of the other libraries that "support" PDF/A, ***will not*** prevent you from modifying PDF in a way that is forbidden by PDF/A... you just need to know what those things are.

So... before merging, you'll want to be sure that the input files don't have any annotations or form fields or any other interactive content.

After merging, add your watermark as page content and be sure your XMP metadata is conforming and you should be OK.

Comment: *Libraries that "support" PDF/A, will not prevent you from modifying PDF in a way that is forbidden by PDF/A.* That's true, but when designing iText 7, we tried to add as many checks as possible (and acceptable in terms of processing speed) to throw an exception when an attempt is made to modify the existing PDF in a way that is forbidden by PDF/A.

Comment: Good point @BrunoLowagie. So my advice would be to create a new blank PDF/A document and append your pages from the other files to *it* rather than merging the existing PDF files. That way you can take advantage of the exceptions.